# LangChain question: It turns out that the LLM cannot see the information in additional_kwargs or id of HumanMessage

Tags: langchain

I am trying to assign meaningful identifiers to the id of HumanMessage for downstream tasks of user-id or item-id. I have two approaches to do this:

Set the identifiers to the id of HumanMessage, but I checked on LangSmith and found that all ids are not visible by the LLM.
Set the identifiers to be a part of additional_kwargs (ie. uid) as shown in the code I pasted. While I can see them in LangSmith, the LLM cannot see them and gives me a negative response.
Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?

```py
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(return_messages=True)
mem_vars = memory.load_memory_variables({})
pretty_print("Memory Variables init", mem_vars)
pretty_print("Memory Variables in str list (buffer_as_str) init", memory.buffer_as_str)

memory.buffer.append(AIMessage(content="This is a Gaming Place"))
mem_vars = memory.load_memory_variables({})
pretty_print("Memory Variables seeded", mem_vars)
pretty_print(
    "Memory Variables in str list (buffer_as_str), seeded", memory.buffer_as_str
)

memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="Hello dudes", id="user-1"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="hi", id="user-2"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="yo yo", id="user-3"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="nice to see you", id="user-4"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="hoho dude", id="user-5"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="o lalala", id="user-L"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="guten tag", id="user-XXXXL"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="Let's get started, ok?", id="user-1"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="YES", id="user-2"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="YEAH....", id="user-3"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="Cool..", id="user-4"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="yup.", id="user-5"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="Great.....", id="user-L"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="alles klar", id="user-XXXXL"))
memory.buffer.append(HumanMessage(content="Opppsssssss.", id="user-5"))
mem_vars = memory.load_memory_variables({})
pretty_print("Memory Variables", mem_vars)
pretty_print("Memory Variables in str list (buffer_as_str)", memory.buffer_as_str)


def convert_memory_to_dict(memory: ConversationBufferMemory) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    """Convert the memory to the dict, role is id, content is the message content."""
    res = [
        """The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from its context. 
If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does not know.

Notice: The 'uid' is user-id, 'role' is user role for human or ai, 'content' is the message content.

"""
    ]
    history = memory.load_memory_variables({})["history"]
    for hist_item in history:
        role = "human" if isinstance(hist_item, HumanMessage) else "ai"
        res.append(
            {
                "role": role,
                "content": hist_item.content,
                "uid": hist_item.id if role == "human" else "",
            }
        )
    return res


cxt_dict = convert_memory_to_dict(memory)
pretty_print("cxt_dict", cxt_dict)


def build_chain_without_parsing(
    model: BaseChatModel,
) -> RunnableSerializable[Dict, str]:
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            SystemMessage(
                content=("You are an AI assistant." "You can handle the query of user.")
            ),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
            HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{query}"),
        ]
    )
    return (
        prompt | model
    )  # comment model, you can see the filled template after invoking the chain.


model = llm
human_query = HumanMessage(
    """Count the number of 'uid'.""",
    id="user-X",
)

res = build_chain_without_parsing(model).invoke(
    {
        "history": cxt_dict,
        "query": human_query,
    }
)
pretty_print("Result", res)
```

The LLM returns me:

```py
AIMessage(
│   content="It seems like you're asking for a count of unique 'uid' values based on the previous conversation structure you've outlined. However, in the conversation snippets you've provided, there are no explicit 'uid' values or a structured format that includes 'uid', 'role', and 'content' fields as you initially described. The conversation appears to be a series of greetings and affirmations without any structured data or identifiers that would allow for counting unique user IDs ('uid').\n\nIf you have a specific dataset or a list of entries that include 'uid', 'role', and 'content' fields, please provide that data. Then, I could help you determine the number of unique 'uid' values within that context."
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set the identifiers to be a part of additional_kwargs (ie. uid) as shown in the code I pasted. While I can see them in LangSmith, the LLM cannot see them and gives me a negative response. Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?

Yes, your understanding is correct. If you look at the implementation of different `BaseChatModel` subclasses (e.g. `ChatOpenAI`, `ChatAnthropic`), you'll see that the final `HumanMessage` that is sent to the LLM **ONLY** includes content from `BaseMessage.content` and does not include any data in `additional_kwargs`.

To clarify, `additional_kwargs` is not meant to contain content to be passed in the LLM prompt. From the [documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/concepts#messages):

> In addition, messages have an additional_kwargs property. This is where additional information about messages can be passed. This is largely used for input parameters that are provider specific and not general. The best known example of this is function_call from OpenAI.

You can try including the `uid` metadata formatted inside `BaseMessage.content`. This may work, but there's no guarantee.

References:

1. `ChatOpenAI` `convert_message_to_dict()`: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.13/libs/community/langchain_community/adapters/openai.py#L125
2. `ChatAnthropic` `_convert_one_message_to_text()`: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.13/libs/community/langchain_community/chat_models/anthropic.py#L35
3. [Messages (LangChain)](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/concepts#messages)